# Best way to manage multiple bits of information for one item?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to wrap my head around all of this, but essentially I am attempting to save multiple bits of information to one item. I want to create a small app that can store an artists information (such as name, genre, location, top tracks, etc).

If I know this information won't be changing anytime soon, should I use an NSDictionary, NSArray?

My main idea is currently to use NSDictionary, then add each dictionary item into an array to output that to a table view. Would that be correct and efficient use of device resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a totally correct way of storing your data.

If you need to save the data you can back up that information in Core Data.

Comment: Thank you sir! This is exactly what I was thinking. Because it's a list of 50 items, I will manually create the dictionary and then back it up to the Core Data.

Answer (score 1):

Store data in Core Data then call NSFetchedResultsController to manipulate data.

Having an array with dictionary is okay for small amount of data.. but as app grows it may have few thousand records.. so its better go with Core data right from the start!

Cheers!